# How to quickly cut out these shapes

Tags: modeling

[image]
I want to cut this out into shapes the model is hallow btw. I need this to make a lantern and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your pattern, it needs to be tileable:

[image]

Array it:

[image]

Use a *Simple Deform* in *Bend* mode to make it bend 360°:

[image]

Give it thickness with a *Solidify* modifier, deform it with a *Lattice* cage:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! this helped out a ton!